# Let $\psi_A(B)=AB-BA$ for $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, Show that $\psi^m_A(B)=\sum_{l=0}^m(-1)^l \binom{m}{l}A^{m-l}BA^l$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ I want to show that $\psi_A^m(B)=\sum_{\ell=0}^m(-1)^\ell \binom{m}{\ell}A^{m-\ell}BA^\ell$ My first idea was to use induction. It follows

$$\psi_A^{m+1}(B)=\psi_A\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^m(-1)^\ell \binom{m}{\ell}A^{m-\ell}BA^\ell\right)=$$
$$A\sum_{\ell=0}^m(-1)^\ell \binom{m}{\ell}A^{m-\ell}BA^\ell-\sum_{\ell=0}^m(-1)^\ell \binom{m}{\ell}A^{m-\ell}BA^\ell A=$$

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^m(-1)^\ell \binom{m}{\ell}A^{m+1-\ell}BA^\ell+\sum_{\ell=0}^m(-1)^{\ell+1} \binom{m}{\ell}A^{m-\ell}BA^{\ell+1}=$$

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^m(-1)^\ell \binom{m}{\ell}A^{m+1-\ell}BA^\ell+\sum_{\ell'=1}^{m+1}(-1)^{\ell'} \binom{m}{\ell'-1}A^{m-\ell'+1}BA^{\ell'}=$$

$$A^{m+1}B+\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^m(-1)^\ell \binom{m+1}{l}A^{m+1-\ell}BA^\ell\right)+(-1)^{m+1}BA^{m+1}=$$

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^{m+1}(-1)^\ell \binom{m+1}{\ell}A^{m+1-\ell}BA^\ell$$

Maybe there is an easier way than using induction or there is some obvious step I am missing. Anyways, thanks for your help.

(Edit: I did not copy the answer beneath, but tried to go through it here on my own.)

Comment: Why do you think this is true? After all, $(AB-BA)^2=ABAB-AB^2A-BA^2B+BABA$. According to your formula, it should be $A^2B-ABA+BA^2$.

Comment: Could it be that I am mistaken a power with a recursion? Original exercise says let $\psi_A(B)=AB-BA$ and that the claim is that $\psi_A^m(B)$ is equal to the sum above. (Remark: $\psi=ad_x(y)$ for Lie-Algebras)

Comment: That's a totally different statement.

Comment: So in this given case $\psi^m_A(B)$ means recursion? So $\psi^2_A(B)=\psi_{A}(AB-BA)$? It was not obvious for me and unfortunately I did not check the case for $n=2$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I am sorry for my confusion I will edit the question and will try it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be fixed, and let $\psi := \psi_A$ to simplify the notations.

Consider $f: B \to AB$ and $g: B\to BA$. Clearly, $f,g$ are endomorphisms of $M_n(\Bbb{R})$. Moreover, associativity implies that $f\circ g= g\circ f$: $A(BA)= (AB)A$ for all $B$.

Therefore, since $\psi = f-g$, using the binomial formula (valid in any ring as long as $f,g$ commute, which is what was proved above), we get $\psi^m = (f-g)^m =\displaystyle\sum_{l=0}^m (-1)^l \binom{m}{l} f^{m-l}g^l$.

Evaluating this formula in $B$ gives $\psi^m(B) =\displaystyle\sum_{l=0}^m (-1)^l \binom{m}{l} A^{m-l}BA^l$ because quite clearly, $f^k(B)= A^k B$ and similarly for $g$.

Comment: Thats a pretty cool way to solve the problem

Comment: And if you look at the proof by induction, it's actually just re-proving the binomial formula

Answer (score 1):

For $m=1$, it is trivial. Let $m\in\mathbb N$ and suppose that it holds for $m$. Then\begin{align*}{\psi_A}^{m+1}(B)&=A{\psi_A}^m(B)-{\psi_A}^m(B)A\\&=\left(\sum_{l=0}^m(-1)^l\binom mlA^{m+1-l}BA^l\right)+\left(\sum_{l=0}^m(-1)^{l+1}\binom mlA^{m-l}BA^{l+1}\right)\\&=A^{m+1}B+\left(\sum_{l=1}^{m-1}(-1)^l\left(\binom ml+\binom m{l-1}\right)A^{m+1-l}BA^l\right)+(-1)^{m+1}BA^{m+1}\\&=\sum_{l=0}^{m+1}(-1)^l\binom{m+1}lA^{m+1-l}BA^l.\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my confusion!

Answer (score 0):

After the issue mentioned by @JoseCarlosSantos in the comments is resolved, following will be useful.

$$\begin{align}(x+y)(x+y)^n &= (x+y)\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}x^iy^{n-i}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}x^{i+1}y^{n-i} + \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}x^{i}y^{n+1-i}\\
&= \binom{n}{n}x^{n+1} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}x^{i+1}y^{n-i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}x^{i}y^{n+1-i} + \binom{n}{0}y^{n+1}\\
&= \binom{n+1}{n+1}x^{n+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i-1}x^{i}y^{n+1-i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}x^{i}y^{n+1-i} + \binom{n+1}{0}y^{n+1} \ \ (*)\\ 
&= \binom{n+1}{n+1}x^{n+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n+1}{i}x^{i}y^{n+1-i} + \binom{n+1}{0}y^{n+1} \\ 
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{i}x^iy^{n+1-i}\end{align}$$

In $(*)$ I replaced $i \leftarrow i+1$.